# strange canvas.getMatrix values on various devices

Tags: android, canvas

I have a strange issue with canvas.getMatrix values in my Android app. For a custom View I have (my class, extending ImageView) the result of getMatrix() on a "brand new" view is various on two devices (and two OSs). Various in a way that does not make sense for me (e.g. not dimension dependent).

- My view is second on the layout, after 64dp which maps to 96px on both devices (Nexus7 and HTC Desire).
- On Nexus the initial matrixFloats[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] result is 0 (then when I start scrolling and zooming it of course changes).
- On HTC Desire (and Kindle Fire) - the starting value is 96.

Is there any difference Canvas Matrix operates between various versions of Android?

Thanks for any advice - hope someone is familiar with that issue.

PS. matrixFloats is a float[9] array that is a result of Matrix getValues(float[]) method.

Answering a question, and sharing my "dirty" solution.

1. This is a canvas.getMatrix() matrix I get out of canvas in my onDraw() method.
2. To get around this (I need this matrix to understand what area of the image on my ImageView was tapped) by adding a param that I set at the very beginning based on the initial state of the matrix.

Comment: What Matrix are you talking about? Where does it come from? If your app is running with hardware acceleration on, the Canvas' matrix will be different from when you run with hardware acceleration off. This is a side effect of rendering to display lists first but both results are correct.